# "omp parallel for" does not work in "omp parallel"

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

I expect to get the following output:

```
My rank is: 0 num is: 0
My rank is: 1 num is: 1
My rank is: 2 num is: 2
My rank is: 3 num is: 3
```

from the following code:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   int my_rank = omp_get_thread_num();

   #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){       
       printf("My rank is: %d num is: %d\n",my_rank, i);       
   }
}
```

But it gives following output:

```
My rank is: 0 num is: 0
My rank is: 0 num is: 1
My rank is: 0 num is: 2
My rank is: 0 num is: 3
My rank is: 2 num is: 0
My rank is: 2 num is: 1
My rank is: 2 num is: 2
My rank is: 2 num is: 3
My rank is: 3 num is: 0
My rank is: 3 num is: 1
My rank is: 3 num is: 2
My rank is: 3 num is: 3
My rank is: 1 num is: 0
My rank is: 1 num is: 1
My rank is: 1 num is: 2
My rank is: 1 num is: 3
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not repeat `parallel`, you are already inside a `parallel` block, so you only need `pragma omp for` for the loop, and each thread executing the `parallel` block will automatically take a chunk of the loop if you specify `pragma omp for`. If you want to specify the number of threads you can do `pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)` and then `pragma omp for`. In any case for such a simple piece of code you can just drop the entire outer block which seems unneeded.

Here's the correct version:

```c
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
{
  int my_rank = omp_get_thread_num();

  #pragma omp for
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){       
      printf("My rank is: %d num is: %d\n", my_rank, i);       
  }
}
```

Or simply:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){       
    printf("My rank is: %d num is: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);       
}
```

Comment: First one is also not working. Second one works but I want to run omp_get_thread_num() once for other purposes.

Comment: @salimtop both examples are correct, if the first one isn't working then there's something else wrong with your code: see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qPTszMez3).

Comment: Oh, sorry I just realize there is no parallel in omp for.  It worked

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [@Marco Bonelli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67810004/omp-parallel-for-does-not-work-in-omp-parallel/67810230#67810230) is spot on, I just want to expand upon it with more information of what is happening behind the scenes.

By default, `nested parallelism` is **disabled**. Nonetheless, one can explicitly **enable** `nested parallelism`, by either:

```
   omp_set_nested(1);
```

or by setting the [OMP_NESTED](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse57.html) environment variable to true.

also from the [OpenMP standard](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf) we know that:

> **When a thread encounters a parallel construct, a team of threads is
> created to execute the parallel region.**
> The thread that encountered the parallel construct becomes
> the master thread of the new team, with a thread number of zero for
> the duration of the new parallel region. All threads in the new team,
> including the master thread, execute the region. Once the team is
> created, the number of threads in the team remains constant for the
> duration of that parallel region.

From [source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/stud.10/819-0501/2_nested.html) you can read the following.

> OpenMP parallel regions can be nested inside each other. **If nested
> parallelism is disabled, then the new team created by a thread
> encountering a parallel construct inside a parallel region consists
> only of the encountering thread.** If nested parallelism is enabled,
> then the new team may consist of more than one thread.

This explains the reason why when you add the second `parallel region` (*i.e.,* *#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)*) there is only one thread *per* team executing the enclosing code (*i.e.,* the *for* loop).  In other words, from the first `parallel region`, `4` threads are created, each of those threads when encountering the second `parallel region`  will create a new team and become the master of that team (i.e., will have the `ID=0` within the newly created team). **However, because you did not explicitly enable the nested parallelism, each of those teams is only composed of a single thread**. Hence, `4` teams with a thread each will execute the *for* loop. Consequently, you will have the following statement:

```
   printf("My rank is: %d num is: %d\n",my_rank, i);
```

being printed `4 x 4 = 16 times` (*i.e.,* the total number of loop iterations multiple by the total number of threads across the `4` teams). This is why you got the following output:

```
My rank is: 0 num is: 0
My rank is: 0 num is: 1
My rank is: 0 num is: 2
My rank is: 0 num is: 3
My rank is: 2 num is: 0
My rank is: 2 num is: 1
My rank is: 2 num is: 2
My rank is: 2 num is: 3
My rank is: 3 num is: 0
My rank is: 3 num is: 1
My rank is: 3 num is: 2
My rank is: 3 num is: 3
My rank is: 1 num is: 0
My rank is: 1 num is: 1
My rank is: 1 num is: 2
My rank is: 1 num is: 3
```

The image below provides a visualization of that flow:

[image]

Bear in mind that in the image above, I am assuming a certain `static` loop distribution of iterations among loops, I am not implying that the loop iterations will always be divided like this across all the implementations of the OpenMP standard.

> I expect to get the following output:
>
> ```
> My rank is: 0 num is: 0
> My rank is: 1 num is: 1
> My rank is: 2 num is: 2
> My rank is: 3 num is: 3
> ```

So clearly what you are look for is:

```
 #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
 for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){       
     printf("My rank is: %d num is: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);       
 }
```

The:

`#pragma omp parallel for`

will create a `parallel region` (as described before), and to the `threads` of that region the iterations of the loop that it encloses will be assigned, using the `default chunk size`, and the `default schedule` which is *typically* `static`. Bear in mind, however, that the `default schedule` might differ among different concrete implementation of the `OpenMP` standard.

From the [OpenMP 5.1](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-1.pdf) you can read a more formal description :

> The worksharing-loop construct specifies that the iterations of one or
> more associated loops will be executed in parallel by threads in the
> team in the context of their implicit tasks. **The iterations are
> distributed across threads that already exist in the team that is
> executing the parallel region to which the worksharing-loop region
> binds**.

[Moreover](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf),

> The parallel loop construct is a shortcut for specifying a parallel
> construct containing a loop construct with one or more associated
> loops and no other statements.

Or informally, `#pragma omp parallel for` is a combination of the constructor `#pragma omp parallel` with `#pragma omp for`.